# Windows Phone 8 ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, scrollviewer

I have two ScrollViewer's in my layout of windows phone app. I'm trying to synchronize both. i'm using VisualTreeHelper.GetChild to find HorizontalScrollBar and then setting ValueChanged event.

It happens that this event is not called whenever scrollviewer is scrolling, so the other scrollviewer scrolling is not smooth.

I had tried many solutions found in internet but it seems nothing is working for me.

Is there any event that i can subscribe in order to achieve this effect?

NOTE: the content of the first ScrollViewer is much longer than the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Try listening to "mouseMove" event on the scrollviewer that you need to base your adjustment on.

```
this.MyScrollViewer.MouseMove += MyScrollViewer_MouseMove;
```

Handle the event in a method like this:

```
public void MyScrollViewer_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
      // Write your manipulation here
}
```

Comment: That's not the event that i need... I think if I set HorizontalOffset binding can work for me. I will try later